# aws ssm start-session .. AWS-StartPortForwardingSession .. hangs

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-systems-manager

I am trying to set up port forwarding between my local PC and an AWS EC2 based on the [AWS SSM port forwarding article](https://awsfeed.com/whats-new/new-port-forwarding-using-aws-system-manager-sessions-manager/)  instance like this:

```
aws ssm start-session --target  i-0822c9a6c52ca7394 \
  --document-name AWS-StartPortForwardingSession --parameters \
 '{"portNumber":["55555"],"localPortNumber":["6666"]}'
```

I already use SSM to access the instance (using [ssm-session](https://github.com/mludvig/aws-ssm-tools)) and have used it to start `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 55555` listening on the port.

The output I get from SSM is just this:

> Starting session with SessionId: jakub.holy@481473109573-0dd8f51cc06ef4469
>
> (And, eventually, after a long while:
>   *SessionId: jakub.holy@481473109573-0dd8f51cc06ef4469 : Your session timed out due to inactivity and has been terminated.*
>   - and I still need to `kill` it.)

at which point it hangs. I have expected, but do not see, the following, right after "Startin session...":

> Port 6666 opened for sessionId ....
>
> Connection accepted for session .....

Any idea why is it hanging and not establishing the port forwarding?

Answer (score 0):

I got this tip from a colleague:

> You might need update ssm-agent on EC2 instance before being able to use port-forwarding feature.
>   When the agent doesn't support port-forwarding the session is hanging with no error message or ends with message "Session  Timed out".

(I am using the agent baked into the Amazon Linux 2 instance, which was v. 2.3.662 while the newest is now 2.3.760.)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you can write to the bucket used for session manager logging (if you have one), and make sure you also grant EC2 the action `s3:GetBucketEncryption`. See [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/setup-instance-profile.html#instance-profile-custom-s3-policy) for more information

Answer (score 0):

You can get this behaviour if the local port is already in use.
You can replicate it by starting two tunnels with the same configuration and the second one will sit there as the port is already in use.